# Creating a random edge to a neighbor that excludes one particular node in Networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm trying to write a function that will remove 2 random edges from a specific node in my graph except an edge with another particular node. I'm using the Python Networkx package. Here's my code:

```
close = nx.closeness_centrality(self.combined_network) #This calculates closeness
self.most_central_node = max(close.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0] identifies the maximum centrality
self.combined_network.add_edge(self.most_central_node, 'bad_apple_Bad_apple') adds an edge from the most central node to a specific node
```

what I'd like to do next is ask self.most_central_node to break 2 edges (randomly) but not to break the one I just created with 'bad_apple_Bad_apple'. I've tried first selecting most_central_node's neighbors using:

```
Neighb = (B.neighbors(most_central_node))
```

That worked, but it returns a list. Now I'm trying to build that list  without "bad_apple_Bad_apple"

I tried:

```
n2 = B.node['bad_apple_0']
n3 = (item for item in Neighb if item not in n2)
```

That doesn't work I think.  When I print n3 in the console I get:
`<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000203845E8>`

What am I doing wrong? I will then need to select 2 of those at random to ask most_central_node to break its edges with them. Can someone point the way on that too?

Comment: n3 is giving you a generator expression.  You can call the next value using `n3.next()` or get all with `list(n3)`. For removing edges: you could get the list of the node's edges and use `numpy.random.choice(edge_list, p=edge_probs)`, where edge_probs is a list of probabilities for each entry.  Set the probability of the edge you wish to preserve to 0 and set the remaining to have equal probability.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. That's helpful but doesn't work in the sense that I need to remove the potential that the edge to the 'bad_apple_Bad_apple' node is removed. Neighb is a list, how do I build a list from that list that does not include 'bad_apple_Bad_apple'? List items are selected numerically right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
if 'bad_apple_0' in Neighb: Neighb.remove('bad_apple_0')
```

Thanks!